# Reliable metric to predict out of sample performance of trading strategy

Tags: machine-learning, performance-evaluation

How can one estimate the performance of a trading strategy on out of sample dataset? Yes, the good old model selection problem. Everyone knows sharpe ratio of your in-sample dataset by itself is a poor metric for the task at hand.

Could other share How they solve this? Perhaps a combination metric and process?

Comment: Combinatorially Purged Cross Validation... presented here (I hadn't noticed before but it seems to be another of our regular contributors!): https://quantoisseur.com/2019/11/05/combinatorial-purged-cross-validation-explained/

Comment: I second this :)

Comment: Hi @Quantoisseur. I don't quite get this. I understand the purpose of purging and embargo, but what is a path? What is this method trying to solve again?

Also, perhaps I'm missing something here. In each train-test set, what are we even doing? And at the end of the cross-validation process, what did we found? Eg. best features?

Comment: Paulsen & Sohl's Sharpe Ratio Information Criterion is applicable to portfolio problems, giving an unbiased estimate of the signal-noise ratio of the selected portfolio. A modification by Pav converts that into confidence intervals. More importantly, all statistics have standard error, you will likely have very small alpha, and shouldn't expect exotic cross-validation to be a magic bullet.